# How to answer "Do you have nothing to do?" correctly

Tags: questions

If I have nothing to do, should I say "yes" or "no"?
I'm confused because both "Yes, I do have nothing to do" and "No, I don't have anything to do" have the same meaning.

Comment: Either would be a 'correct' answer, but "No, I don't/haven't" would be more natural.

Comment: If you give a single-word answer, there's every chance you'll be asked the follow-up question 1: *Did you mean **Yes** you **do** have nothing to do?* **OR** 2: *Did you mean **No** you **don't** have anything to do?*